# Access the first object in grouby list of lists

Tags: c#-4.0

GroupBy creates a list of lists of the objects that I'm sorting. I need just the first element in each list

```
List<string> topFive = listOfObjects.GroupBy(x=>x.names).OrderByDescending(x=>x.Count())...
```

Ok, so I have a list of objects, in descending order by how many objects are in each list. I need to retrieve 1 object  from each list, i.e. I need to retrieve the first object in each nested list and put it in a new list so I can .select the .names property

The confusion is arising from the fact that GroupBy is creating a list where there are multiple objects in a list, where that list is in an element of an external list. So I need to extract 1 object from each NESTED list

I have been scanning stack overflow for the last 2 hours and lack the keywords to find a relevant answer.

this is my best guess but doesn't actually work

```
List<string> topFive = listOfObjects.GroupBy(x => x.names).OrderByDescending(x => x.Count()).Select(x => x.Select(y => y.names));
```

Comment: can someone please help?

Is SelectMany going to work? I'm not sure how to use it, and it isn't letting me access the properties on the objects still....

Comment: `List<string> topFive = listOfObjects.GroupBy(x => x.names).OrderByDescending(x => x.Count()).SelectMany(x => x.Select(y=>y.names).Take(5)).ToList<string>();`

This is as far as i've gotten, this still doesn't work, but this is more along the track that I need

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried:

```
topFive.First().names
```

Comment: this does not work there is no .names property to a list. .First() only refers to the first list in the list of lists

Comment: group by creates a list of lists of the objects that I'm sorting. I need just the first element in each list

Answer (score 0):

```
List<string> topFive = listOfObjects.GroupBy(x => x.names).OrderByDescending(x => x.Count()).SelectMany(x => x.Select(y=>y.names).Distinct()).Take(5).ToList();
```

Figured out my own answer again.

Select many is selecting names from each object in my list of lists, and only extracting distinct names to a new list, taking the first 5 to a new list.